# Understanding the value of $\gamma$ parameter, so that the given process is a martingale.

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, martingales, poisson-process

I have a Poisson process of $X_t$ with rate $\lambda=\tilde\lambda.$ Now, given $M_t = X_t + \gamma\cdot t$ I want to uderstand, for which values of $\gamma$, $M_t$ is a martingale.

I know, that in order for $M_t$ to be a martingale, the following should hold (assuming the natural filtration, and given that $X_t$ is the only term of $M_t$ from which the variability comes):

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[M_{n+1}| \mathcal{F_n}\right] = M_n
$$

I have applied the above condition on what I have for $M_t$, but I may have done a mistake, since for some reason $\gamma$ for me does not come to be a constant, what seems quite weird..

$$
\mathbb{E}[M_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] = \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1} + \gamma(n+1)|\mathcal{F}_n] = (\text{since }n \text{ is fixed}) = \gamma(n+1) + \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] =\\= (\text{here I decided to add and subtract }X_n)=X_n + \gamma n + \gamma + \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] - X_n = M_n +\\+\left(\gamma - X_n + \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n]\right)\implies \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] + (\gamma - X_n) = 0~(\text{for }M_n\text{ to be a martingale}). 
$$
That is, we have to have: $\mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}|\mathcal{F}_n] = X_n - \gamma \Longleftrightarrow \mathbb{E}[X_{n+1}] = X_n - \gamma \Longleftrightarrow \tilde\lambda=X_n-\gamma$. So that I finally obtain that:
$$
\gamma = X_n - \tilde\lambda.
$$
I am totally sure this result is incorrect, since $\gamma$ is definitely not supposed to involve the variable term. But how can I then obtain it, and what is my mistake?

I would appreciate any help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a martingale $(M_t)$ the mean $EM_t=EM_{t+1}$. So we must have  $E(X_t+\gamma t)=E(X_{t+1}+\gamma ((t+1)))$ which gives $t \overline{ \lambda}+\gamma t=(t+1) \overline{ \lambda}+\gamma (t+1)$. Hence, we must have $\gamma =-\overline{ \lambda}$. I will let you try to prove (using independence of increments of $(X_t)$)  that this value of $\gamma$ works. (I can post details if necessary).

Comment: Hmm, well, I guess your result is absolutely correct, just I don't understand the following: on the lecture, we were told that the martingale is a process, so that the conditional expectation of the $(n+1)^{st}$ value in a sequence (given all previous values) is equal to the $n^{th}$ value. Then, how, regarding this, to proceed with $\mathbb{E}[X_t+\gamma t] = \mathbb{E}[X_0 + \gamma \cdot 0]$, if these values are strongly spaced apart in the sequence? Thank you for your help!

Comment: $E(M_{n+1}|\mathcal F_n)=M_n$. Take expectation on both sides. You get $EM_{n+1}=EM_n$ for all $n$. So $EM_{n}$ does not depend on $n$ @O.spectrum

Comment: Thank you for clarification, just I still don't understand why $EM_{n+1} = EM_{n}$ implies $EM_t = EM_0$, as you have written? Shouldn't that only hold for neighboring values in the sequence? I mean, $EM_t = EM_{t-1}$ (not $M_0$, or am I mistaken in this as well?)

Comment: What can you say about a sequence of real numbers such that any term is equal to the next? Do not over-think.

Comment: @O.spectrum Have you heard of something  called 'Proof by induction? Prove that $a_n=a_{n+1}$ for all $n \geq 0$ implies $a_n=a_0$ for all $n$. Anyway, I have modified my answer .

Comment: oh, that's true, I haven't thought of it at first, so basically we can create a descending chain of expected values, leading us to $EM_0$, I see. Thank you a lot!